# How to hyperlink name part in \citet using natbib numerical and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, natbib

I am using natbib and unsrtnat style for numerical citation with hyperref package.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[square, super, sort]{natbib} 
 \usepackage[dvips,
             bookmarks,
             bookmarksopen = true,
             bookmarksnumbered = true,
             breaklinks = true,
             linktocpage,
             pagebackref,
             colorlinks = true,
             linkcolor = blue,
             urlcolor  = blue,
             citecolor = red,
             anchorcolor = green,
             hyperindex = true,
             hyperfigures]{hyperref}

 \begin{document}
 \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
  some text...\citet{ref1}
   other text
   \end{document}

  % some bibliography file
  % test.bib
  @Article {ref1, author = Author1, title = Title1, year = 2010}
```

`\citet{ref1}` results in Author1 et al. [1] where only [1] is hyperlinked to the reference. I would like that name part of citation (Author1 et al.) is also hyperlinked. How to make that work?

Answer (score 8):

Under numeric citation labels `natbib` sets names with the `\NAT@test` command, defined in `natbib.sty`. Using `etoolbox` you can patch `\NAT@test` to mark the name list with an additional hyperlink.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,super,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\NAT@test}{\else \NAT@nm}{\else \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nm}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading, Mass.},
  year = {1994}}
@Book{adams,
  title = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author = {Douglas Adams},
  series = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year = {1980}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{adams}, \citet{companion}, \citet{adams,companion}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What bibliography-style is this ?(I use BiBTeX in scientific workplace)

Comment: @Audrey: Would you want to take a look at my question here : <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199942/natbib-display-hyperlinked-author-year-part-in-citet-and-citep-using-numerica> ?