# Natbib: Display hyperlinked author-year part in \citet and \citep using numerical (superscripted) option

Tags: hyperref, natbib

I want to display an hyperlinked author-year citation with the `super` option in the `natbib` package like this:

`\citet` : **Lancaster et al. (1999)** **(19)**
`\citep` : **(Lancaster et al., 1999)** **(19)**

With `\usepackage[round,super]{natbib}`, only citation number (here for example :**`(19)`**) is hyperlinked. I want to display an hyperlink on both author-year and number whether I use textual (`\citet`) or parenthesized (`\citep`) citation.

Here's an MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,french]{article} %% use 'article' so that output fits on one page
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliob.bib}
@article{Lancaster99,
   title={A new approach to {MSEs} Management},
   author={Lancaster, James R. and Drauster, Mikael F. and Logan, Richard},
   journal={Journal of International Research on Management},
   volume={74},
   number={2},
   pages={132-157},
   year={1999},
   publisher={JSTOR}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[round,super]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Textual citation:~\citep{Lancaster99}

Parenthesized citation:~\citet{Lancaster99}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Biblio}  
\end{document}
```

Is that possible to get the display I want ?

Comment: @Mico : here : <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76067/how-to-hyperlink-name-part-in-citet-using-natbib-numerical-and-hyperref?rq=1> a similair example of what I want to display. There is no redundancy. I want just numerical citations with hyperlinked author-year part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution comes in two parts. First, in order to make the name and year information part of the hyperlink, we add the code provided by @Audrey in her answer to the posting [How to hyperlink name part in \citet using natbib numerical and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76067/5001). Second, we define two new macros, called (not very creatively, I'm afraid) `\mycitet` and `\mycitep`, which mimic the behavior of `\citet` and `\citep` in the authoryear citation style, but with the addition of the superscripted entry number.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,french]{article} %% use 'article' so that output fits on one page
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliob.bib}
@article{Lancaster99,
   title={A new approach to {MSEs} Management},
   author={Lancaster, James R. and Drauster, Mikael F. and Logan, Richard},
   journal={Journal of International Research on Management},
   volume={74},
   number={2},
   pages={132-157},
   year={1999},
   publisher={JSTOR}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[round,super]{natbib}

%% The following lines are straight from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76075/5001
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\NAT@test}{\else \NAT@nm}{\else \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nm}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

%% Provide custom macros to mimic the look created by \citet and \citep
\newcommand{\mycitet}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1}) \citep{#1}}
\newcommand{\mycitep}[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}) \citep{#1}}

\begin{document}
\mycitet{Lancaster99}

\mycitep{Lancaster99}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Biblio}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Mico: I want to display also an hyperlinked year part. This is the difference between my question and the solution provided by @Audrey. Whether I use `\citet` or `\citep` I want both author-year and superscripted numbers to be hyperlinked. Thanks!

Comment: @Houssem - Thanks for providing this clarification. I'll provide a modified answer.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! This is exactly what I wanted:-)